# AWS glue job arguments error - Error parsing parameter '--arguments': Expected: ',', received: ''' for input:

Tags: aws-cli, aws-glue

I have created a `pyspark script` (glue job) and trying to run it through AWS CLI. In this command passing an argument name **FILTER_CONDITION**, the value of this argument is a date. When I tried to pass the date in a single quote (as mentioned in the below command) getting an error.

Command:

```
aws glue start-job-run --job-name myjob_test --arguments="--FILTER_CONDITION":"REPORT_DT=\'2019-01-01\'"
```

Error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--arguments': Expected: ',', received: ''' for
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape quotes using back slash. I have used below command to start a Glue job with arguments and it ran fine with out any issues:

```
aws glue start-job-run --job-name test2 --arguments "{\"--FILTER_CONDITION\": \"REPORT_DT='2019-01-01'\"}"
```